# matplotlib: colorbar make subplots unequal size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I make two subplots with a common shared colorbar. So naturally I want to plot the colorbar only once.
However, when I do so, then my subplots become unequal in size.
How to place the colorbar outside the subplots on the right?

[image: subplots with unequal size]

Minimal working example below

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

res = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, res)

y = np.sin(x)
z = np.cos(x)
y2 = -np.sin(x)+0.4
z2 = 0.5*np.cos(2*x)

fig_width = 200/25.4                                                                                       
fig_height = 100/25.4                                                                                      
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fig_width, fig_height))                                                          
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 2, wspace=0)                                                                      
(ax, ax2) = gs.subplots(sharey='row') 
images = []
images.append(ax.scatter(x, y, c=z))
images.append(ax2.scatter(x, y2, c=z2))
vmin = min(image.get_array().min() for image in images)
vmax = max(image.get_array().max() for image in images)
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
for im in images:
    im.set_norm(norm)
cbar = fig.colorbar(images[0], ax=ax2)
cbar.set_label("mylabel", loc='top')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try passing axes=[ax,ax2] to color instead of ax=ax2?

Comment: Using `ax=[ax,ax2]` places the colorbar in the middle of the right plot. But the sizes are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 1) pass the two axes as `ax`,  and 2) move `tight_layout` before `colorbar`:

```
# other stuff
fig.tight_layout()
cbar = plt.colorbar(images[0], ax=(ax,ax2))
# other - other stuff
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: magic, and moving `tight_layout` does not even mess up my layout :-)
Only issue: I had to use a list `[ax, ax2]', a tuple `(ax, ax2)` would not work.